# Lookup-map role mapper configuration on MONDRIAN

Tags: pentaho, mondrian, pentaho-cde, saiku, pentaho-ctools

> Dear Mondrian/Pentaho BI server team

I am trying to implement this security options in Mondrian schema and currently am facing issues to get around with it. I am using pentaho biserver 5.0.1 Community edition.

1) Tried Listing 6.3. Lookup-map role mapper configuration by editing pentahoObjects.spring.xml as below (un-commented this portion) and restarted the biserver.`<bean id="Mondrian-UserRoleMapper" >name="Mondrian-SampleLookupMap-UserRoleMapper"class="org.pentaho.platform.plugin.action.mondrian.mapper.MondrianLookupMapUserRoleListMapper" scope="singleton"><property name="lookupMap"> <map><entry key="suzy" value="suzy" /><!-- <entry key="ceo" value="M_CEO" /><entry key="cto" value="M_CTO" /><entry key="dev" value="M_DEV" /> --><entry key="Power User" value="Power User" /></map></property></bean>`

> 2) Created a user and role (both) named as suzy in Pentaho. Assigned the user suzy with the role suzy in Pentaho.

3) Designed the Mondrian schema which is working fine when tested through Saiku analytics without adding grants. However when added the following code in Mondrian schema xml file `<Role name="suzy"> 
<SchemaGrant access="none"> 
</SchemaGrant> 
</Role`

> and while testing through the visualization tool (saiku). the schema doesn't show. Knowing that i have added the following resctriction on my schema.

```
<Role name="suzy">
    <SchemaGrant access="none">
        <CubeGrant cube="Client creations" access="all">
        <!--    <HierarchyGrant hierarchy="[Store]" access="custom" rollupPolicy="partial" topLevel="[Store].[Store Country]">
                <MemberGrant member="[Store].[USA].[CA]" access="all"/>
                <MemberGrant member="[Store].[USA].[CA].[Los Angeles]" access="none"/>
                </HierarchyGrant>
                <HierarchyGrant hierarchy="[Customers]" access="custom" rollupPolicy="full" topLevel="[Customers].[State Province]" bottomLevel="[Customers].[City]">
                <MemberGrant member="[Customers].[USA].[CA]" access="all"/>
                <MemberGrant member="[Customers].[USA].[CA].[Los Angeles]" access="none"/>
            </HierarchyGrant>
            <HierarchyGrant hierarchy="[Gender]" access="none"/> -->
        </CubeGrant>
    </SchemaGrant>
</Role>
```

> Please all i dearly seek your advise